# 5 Button clicks to change object colour five different sequential colors

Tags: android

In my android project in one screen I have a button and a separate object that has a black background. When I click the button the separate objects color should change to white and the next click it should change to yello, then orange then red.

I have searched for weeks trying to find something to help my project with android studio and java on a windows 7 pc. Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: use a button, and a int value. press the button, start int at 0. as soon as you press the button, add 1 to the int. in the same code, if (int == 1){change color} etc. its easy java code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your activity should look like this:

```
int counter = -1;
int[] colors = {0xffffffff, 0xffffff00, 0xffff6600, 0xffff0000, 0xff000000};

Button buttonColored;
Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    buttonColored = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonColored);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter++;
            if (counter > colors.length - 1) {
                counter = 0;
            }
            buttonColored.setBackgroundColor(colors[counter]);
        }
    });
}
```

`buttonColored` is a button to be colored when clicking `button`

 `counter` is a variable that takes all the values from 0 to 4, incremented every time `button` is clicked and reset to 0 when it is 5